# Modifying a Linq query to add another condition

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I have a method below pulling specific fields that have null values.
Every record in the table has a status field of 1 or 0. 1 is active and 0 is inactive.

For the query below I only want to pull data for active records i.e status = 1

How can I modify this query to put in the condition for status = 1?

```
        public List<FileModel> GetMyData()
        {
            var collectedData = _context.MyUploads.AsNoTracking().Where(t =>
                    t.FirstName == null ||
                    t.LastName == null ||
                    t.EmailAddress == null ||
                    t.Telephone == null) 
                .Select(x => _mapper.Map<FileModel>(x))
                .ToList();
            return collectedData;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain two `Where` Linq extension method calls right after one another, like so:

```
 public List<FileModel> GetMyData()
 {
    var collectedData = _context.MyUploads.AsNoTracking().Where(t =>
            t.FirstName == null ||
            t.LastName == null ||
            t.EmailAddress == null ||
            t.Telephone == null)
        .Where(t => t.status == 1) // added this line...
        .Select(x => _mapper.Map<FileModel>(x))
        .ToList();
    return collectedData;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should just be able to change the where condition to the below

```
.Where(t => (t.FirstName == null || t.LastName == null || t.EmailAddress == null || t.Telephone == null) && t.status == 1)
```

The && means and, so its saying those fields are null and the status equals 1.

Comment: I still want to be able to test those fields for null and return them . Not just status == 1

Comment: 2 things I want to achieve. Pull the rows with the null fields for fields that are active.

Comment: then you can either chain it like glen's answer or wrap all the null checks in parathesis and add && t.status == 1. i.e (t => t.FirstName == null || t.LastName == null || t.EmailAddress == null || t.Telephone == null) && t.status == 1. I updated my answer to use the parathensis